# Get the required stack object on filter

Tags: javascript, stack

Say My stack has objects in this way .. `[obj1 ,obj2 , obj3 ,  obj1]`

I have 2 similar `obj1`.

Now on filter for `obj1`.... I want the right most obj1 to get selected first... but it always the leftmost `obj1`
 may be since it was added first...FIFO

Please tell me how to filter LIFO

Here is my code

```
var obj = stack.filter(function ( obj ) {

    return obj.id === 'somevalue';

    })[0];
```

**Above code returns `obj1` (which is leftmost)**

It always filter and gives the object based on FIFO.... I want LIFO .. means the rightmost `obj1` to return first and than second right most and so on .

Comment: just reverse your array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a copy of the list and use [`.reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) to reverse the list first before filtering.

```
var obj = [].slice.call(stack).reverse().filter(function ( obj ) {
  return obj.id === 'somevalue';
})[0];
```

If you have a big list, I'd use a `for` loop starting from the end of the array, and returning when a match is found. That's going to avoid running through the whole list.

```
var obj = (function() {
  for(var i = stack.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if(stack[i].id === 'somevalue') {
      return stack[i];
    }
  }
})();
```

Comment: yea reverse works fine ,,,, but i think i must reverse the stack back after requiered filter otherwise it will remain reversed ...Am I right ????

Comment: Yes, you're right. `.reverse()` mutates the array. You could create a copy of the array by calling `Array.prototype.slice.call(stack)` first, but using the `for` loop approach is more elegant, I think.

Comment: after reverse filter m calling stack.reverse(); ... will that be ok

Comment: It'll work, but it's very inefficient, especially for big lists. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

get the last item in stack,

```
var obj = stack.filter(function ( obj ) {

    return obj.id === 'somevalue';

})[stack.length -1];
```

Comment: no..... i want obj1 to return so i have to use filter ,,,, pop wil pop out any obj on top